# Select is not working in the hasMany Relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have surveys and survey_votes table. the table structure is like

Table: surveys

- id
- title
- ... other fields

Table: survey_votes

- id
- ... other fields
- survey_id
- mark ( Number of votes )

and the relationship between these 2 tables is like.

```
class Survey extends Model
{
    public function votes() {
        return $this->hasMany(SurveyVote::class);
    }
}


class SurveyVote extends Model
{
    public function survey() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Survey::class);
    }
}
```

Now I fetching surveys with survey votes using with(). but getting empty results.

```
$surveys = Survey::with(['votes' => function ( $query ) {
    $query->select(\DB::raw('SUM(mark) total_votes'))->groupBy('survey_id');
}])->get();
```

and the strange thing is when I remove this `$query->select()` then it's working well.
I have referred to all the links regarding this issue, but not work.

[image]

**Note:** I am using Laravel v5.8

Your suggestion is valuable for me, Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to select the foreign key in `with()` clause that joins these 2 tables

```
$surveys = Survey::with(['votes' => function ( $query ) {
    $query->select(['survey_id',\DB::raw('SUM(mark) total_votes')])->groupBy('survey_id');
}])->get();
```

Or if you are using newer version of laravel then you can use [**`withSum()`**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions)

```
$surveys = Survey::withSum('votes', 'mark')->get()
```

Another way to use `withCount` with a little tweak to get sum of marks

```
$surveys = Survey::withCount(['votes as total_votes' => function ( $query ) {
    $query->select(\DB::raw('SUM(mark)'));
}])->get();
```

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid, I have checked this, but not working for me

Comment: @MiteshRathod that's weird because I have tested the same condition on local env

Comment: @MiteshRathod I have added another variation to pick the sum of column using withCount, please review

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be because you are not returning the query from your inside function. Try if this helps;

```
$surveys = Survey::with(['votes' => function ( $query ) {
    return $query->select(\DB::raw('SUM(mark) total_votes'))->groupBy('survey_id');
}])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple answer: the select method requires you to supply the foreign key on hasMany relationship, just the way it requires the primary key on belongsTo relationship.